# How to define this variable below?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Cancel button which appears when the user is uploading a file. If the user wishes to cancel a file upload then they can by clicking on the Cancel Button and it would display the cancel message to user.

The only problem when attempting this is that it is stating that cancel_image_file_name is undefined in the stopImageUpload function where I want to display the message. But I did define this in the startImageUpload function. So my question is that how can I grab cancel_image_file_name from the startImageUpload function and define it in the stopImageUpload function?

Below is the code showing the 2 functions:

startImageUpload function:

```
var cancelimagecounter = 0;

function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagefilename){

    cancelimagecounter++;

            var _cancelimagecounter = cancelimagecounter;

    $('.imageCancel').on("click", function(event) {
        var cancel_image_file_name = $(this).attr('cancel_image_file_name');

    return stopImageUpload(2, cancel_image_file_name);

});       
      return true;
}
```

stopImageUpload function:

```
var imagecounter = 0;

function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      imagecounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else if (success == 2){
          result = '<span class="imageemsg">' + cancel_image_file_name + ' Upload Was Cancelled!</span><br/><br/>';
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      return true;   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript variables have function-level scope, to get `cancel_image_file_name` in your other function too, define it ***outside of both functions***.

---

BTW, you can use `imagefilename` from your `stopImageUpload` function because you are already passing it to that function:

```
return stopImageUpload(2, cancel_image_file_name);
```

So in your `stopImageUpload` function, change line:

```
result = '<span class="imageemsg">' + cancel_image_file_name + ' Upload Was Cancelled!</span><br/><br/>';
```

To:

```
result = '<span class="imageemsg">' + imagefilename + ' Upload Was Cancelled!</span><br/><br/>';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, this has removed the error. I just have one little question, for imagefilename it is displaying "undefined". So for example if I try to cancel file "Tulips.png", then it should display "Tulips.png Upload Was Canceled" but instead it is displaying "undefined Upload was Canceled", do you know why this is?

Comment: @user1391585: Make sure that this line `var cancel_image_file_name = $(this).attr('cancel_image_file_name')` is returning some value.

Answer (score 0):

You're already passing in the value as the second parameter to "stopImageUpload", "imagefilename".  Just use that.

In fact elsewhere *in that same function* you're using the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your code like this:

```
(function() {
    var cancelimagecounter = 0,
        imagecounter = 0,
        cancel_image_file_name;
    window.startImageUpload = function(imageuploadform,imagefilename) {
        ...
            cancel_image_file_name = ... // (remove the var)
        ...
    };
    window.stopImageUpload = function(success,imagefilename) {
        ...
        // cancel_image_file_name is not undefined now.
    };
})();
```